# Does VNC handle dynamic IP address automatically?

Tags: networking, vnc, dynamic-ip

I'm new, and I'm setting up a Raspberry Pi with VNC server that will be always ON behind a normal router on a Dynamic IP address location.  Is VNC server going to work seamlessly if/when my IP address changes ? Or am I going to discover I can't communicate, and do setup all over again ? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

In short, VNC won't be the problem. DNS - is what you need to function. If DNS can't function properly, there is Netbios as a fallback. Your next step depends on where you are plugging in the Raspberry Pi. If it is somewhere on your own home network, then your router needs to be able to provide DNS or you need Netbios working at the R PI. If the router does not support it, or if you aren't sure, then I recommend assigning the R Pi a static IP that you know is available on that network and using that static IP from now on.

Like I said, if this is on a corp network that has a properly configured DHCP server on that network, then DNS should also work seamlessly. If it is a home network, you'll probably just want to go with a static IP to avoid problems down the road.